# Single Selection not working in Extjs Grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

This is how I set up my selection model for my grid :

```
var selM = Ext.create('Ext.selection.Model', {
    mode: 'SINGLE',
    toggleOnClick: true,
    allowDeselect:true
});
```

And then in my table I add this as a configuration paramater :

```
var packageGrid = Ext.create('js.grid.MyGrid', {
    selModel: selM 
});
```

The ***MULTI*** selection is disabled, which is great. However now *nothing* remains selected. If I click on a row the highlighting disappears as soon as I move the mouse away.

This could be an extjs bug. I have tried the other parameter 'SIMPLE' as well.

Here is a fiddle which shows my problem :

http://jsfiddle.net/fgkb8yw5/1/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RowModel` is the default so you can simply use:

```
selModel: {
  mode: 'SINGLE'
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/8mra2het/1/

Comment: tried to use that before but didn't work. But now it does. Thanks!

Comment: I think i was using this which didn't work : selModel: new Ext.selection.Model({mode: 'SINGLE'})

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, `Ext.selection.Model` is the abstract class - which shouldn't be instantiated directly.  Normally - when you specify the `selModel` declaratively, the grid component will implement one of the grid-context appropriate sub-classes:

- [`Ext.selection.CellModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.CellModel)
- [`Ext.selection.RowModel`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.selection.RowModel)

I [updated your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fgkb8yw5/2/) using `RowModel` to demonstrate.

Comment: ah i understand. Wish it would be made somehow clearer that Ext.selection.Model is abstract. Thanks :)